# Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed using Docker

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hi i'm using docker compose to handle all of my configuration.

i have mongo, node, redis, and elastic stack.

But i can't get my redis connect to my node app.

Here is my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.6
    container_name: "backend-mongo"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - "./data/db:/data/db"
  redis:
    image: redis:4.0.7
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    user: redis
  adminmongo:
    container_name: "backend-adminmongo"
    image: "mrvautin/adminmongo"
    ports: 
      - "1234:1234"
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.1.1
    container_name: "backend-elastic"
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - esnet
  web:
    container_name: "backend-web"
    build: .
    ports:
     - "8888:8888"
    environment:
     - MONGODB_URI=mongodb://mongo:27017/backend
    restart: always
    depends_on: 
     - mongo
     - elasticsearch
     - redis
    volumes:
     - .:/backend
     - /backend/node_modules
volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
networks:
  esnet:
```

Things to notice:

- The redis is already running ( I can ping the redis)
- I don't have any services running on my host only from the container
- Other containers (except redis) work well
- I've tried this method below

`const redisClient = redis.createClient({host: 'redis'});
 const redisClient = redis.createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1');
 const redisClient = redis.createClient(6379, 'redis');`

I'm using

- docker 17.12
- xubuntu 16.04

How can i connect my app to my redis container?

Comment: Can you try `const redisClient = redis.createClient(6379, 'redis');`

Comment: @TarunLalwani i've tried that too, and gained the same result

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Comment: @Xaraphena hostname should not be 127.0.0.1 but the redis container name itself

Comment: @Developer perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

adding 
`hostname: redis`

under redis section fix this issue.

So it will be something like this,

```
redis:
    image: redis:4.0.7
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
    hostname: redis
```

Comment: when you use service name as `redis` you don't need to specify the `hostname: redis` the redis will be reachable by it service name itself